# Can purify find out access violation on stack variables?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, access-violation, purify

Currently I am using Valgrind to check memory leak and take Purify as an alternative. Valgrind can find out the access violation on an array created in heap but not in stack.

```
char* a = static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(char) * 5));
a[7] = 'c';
printf("%c\n", a[7]);
free(a);
```

Valgrind points of invalid write and read in the above code, but not the following code.

```
char a[5] = {0};
a[7] = 'c';
printf("%c\n", a[7]);
```

Can Purify identify the access violation of the both blocks of code?

Answer (score 0):

According to the user's guide (ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/v2003/purify/html/ht_m_sbr.htm) and (ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/v2003/purify/html/ht_m_sbw.htm), Purify can detect both stack boundary read and write.

However, trying your actual examples only the violation on heap data was detected also by Purify.  I have only tested the latest version from IBM (7.0.1), both for Linux and Solaris.

You may want to look at -fsanitize=address for gcc 4.8 and later.